# Particular Solution of second order Linear Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got a problem with finding particular solution of: 
$$y''-y'-6y=12x.$$
My homogeneous solution is :
$$y=C_1e^{3x}+C_2e^{-2x}.$$

When i'm trying to find particular solution i'm using the Method of undetermined coefficients.

My solution here is : $$y_{\text{particular}} = -2x$$

And the answer i should get is: $$y_{\text{particular}} = -2x+\frac{1}{3}.$$

How can i get that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try a particular solution in the form $y+p = a + bx.$

Answer (score 0):

Searching a particular solution of the form $y=ax+b$ we find:

$$
y'=a\quad y''=0 \Rightarrow -a-6(ax+b)=12x \iff(-6b-a)-6ax=12x
$$
so:
$-6b-a =0$ and $-6a=12$ and $a=-2$, $b=1/3$.